# Do you get to do this again in the campaign?

Tags: doom-eternal

The title is vague because I don't want to spoil the game.

On what I think is the 3rd level of Doom Eternal, you get to do the following:

> take control of a Revenant demon.

Within the campaign does anything like this happen again?  With other demons perhaps?

Comment: Not within the campaign, but in the multiplayer mode there are lots of options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is the only instance in the campaign where you

> control another character other than the Doom Slayer

Comment: Heya! You completed the campaign and know this, or another source?

Comment: @Mathias711 I have completed the campaign including all optional content